# list index error with numba guvectorize

Tags: python, anaconda, numba, numba-pro

I am new to numba / numbapro. I was trying to run one of the examples, this one about generalised Ufuncs with guvectorize:

(Here the link to the example): http://docs.continuum.io/numbapro/quickstart.html#numbapro-guvectorize

```
import numbapro as numbapro

@numbapro.guvectorize(['void(int32[:], int32[:])'], '(n)->()')
def sum_row(inp, out):
    """
    Sum every row

    function type: two arrays
                   (note: scalar is represented as an array of length 1)
    signature: n elements to scalar
    """
    tmp = 0.
    for i in range(inp.shape[0]):
        tmp += inp[i]
    out[0] = tmp
```

I get this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-79514a184595> in <module>()
----> 1 @numbapro.guvectorize(['void(int32[:], int32[:])'], '(n)->()')
      2 def sum_row(inp, out):
      3     """
      4     Sum every row
      5 

/users/adelacalle/anaconda_linux/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/decorators.pyc in wrap(func)
    117         for fty in ftylist:
    118             guvec.add(fty)
--> 119         return guvec.build_ufunc()
    120 
    121     return wrap

/users/adelacalle/anaconda_linux/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/ufuncbuilder.pyc in build_ufunc(self)
    149 
    150         for sig, cres in self.nb_func.overloads.items():
--> 151             dtypenums, ptr = self.build(cres)
    152             dtypelist.append(dtypenums)
    153             ptrlist.append(utils.longint(ptr))

/users/adelacalle/anaconda_linux/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/ufuncbuilder.pyc in build(self, cres)
    167         signature = cres.signature
    168         wrapper = build_gufunc_wrapper(ctx, cres.llvm_func, signature,
--> 169                                        self.sin, self.sout)
    170         ctx.engine.add_module(wrapper.module)
    171         ptr = ctx.engine.get_pointer_to_function(wrapper)

/users/adelacalle/anaconda_linux/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/wrappers.pyc in build_gufunc_wrapper(context, func, signature, sin, sout)
    143     for i, (typ, sym) in enumerate(zip(signature.args, sin + sout)):
    144         ary = GUArrayArg(context, builder, arg_args, arg_dims, arg_steps, i,
--> 145                          step_offset, typ, sym, sym_dim)
    146         step_offset += ary.ndim
    147         arrays.append(ary)

/users/adelacalle/anaconda_linux/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/wrappers.pyc in __init__(self, context, builder, args, dims, steps, i, step_offset, typ, syms, sym_dim)
    207         self.array = arycls(context, builder)
    208         self.array.data = builder.bitcast(self.data, self.array.data.type)
--> 209         self.array.shape = cgutils.pack_array(builder, self.shape)
    210         self.array.strides = cgutils.pack_array(builder, self.strides)
    211         self.array_value = self.array._getpointer()

/users/adelacalle/anaconda_linux/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/cgutils.pyc in pack_array(builder, values)
    257 def pack_array(builder, values):
    258     n = len(values)
--> 259     ty = values[0].type
    260     ary = Constant.undef(Type.array(ty, n))
    261     for i, v in enumerate(values):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I do not found more documentation than this link. Am I doing something wrong? I found that this happens when there is an empty bracket in the signature. 
I am running this on a linux machine, and my version of numbapro is 0.14.1

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 2):

Finally I arrived to a conclusion by myself. You can allocate an actual array of n elements, so you can write as a signature `(n)->(n)` instead of `(n)->()`. There must be an error on the documentation, or it is outdated.

However, this is not efficient as we have to allocate the whole array and it will be a waste of memory (Although it works!). Even more, use `guvectorize` to sum elements across the array it is probably the best, neat and efficient way to do it, so I use @jit.